# Support pushstate and non pushstate url in Aurelia

Tags: c#, aurelia, pushstate, webapi

I have an aurelia app which currently does not use pushstate. We are updating it to work with pushstate so that urls now do not contain the '#'.

We have a requirement to support the old urls because they may exist in some old reports.

Is there a way to have aurelia backward compatible? (i.e http://example.com/item/#/22 and http://example.com/item/22 both go the same page.)

Thanks

Comment: Instead of supporting the old url's in your app, wouldn't it be possible to create a server rewrite rule that rewrites the old url's to the new unhashed ones? Seems more like the place to do this IMO